# What exactly is a voyeur shot in cinematography?

Tags: video, filming

What exactly is a voyeur shot in cinematography?  Is this movement or style?  The only thing I can find online is basically perverted stuff.  Where can I find an example?

Comment: Where have you heard of this style?  I've never heard of it as a style.

Answer (score 1):

I've not heard of it referred to as a style.  The only thing I could imagine it would be is trying to emulate a style similar to the voyeuristic feel which would probably be made up of roughly shot and edited clips of what would normally be a private, intimate scene, but I am not familiar with a "voyeur shot" as a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Better late then never. This is a typical voyeurshot